# Optimize Django Query with two joins

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a query that implies three tables:

```
hotels = models.Hotel.objects.filter(
    contracts__rate_tables__start_date__lte=check_in,
    contracts__rate_tables__due_date__gte=check_in,
).distinct()
```

Where `contracts` and `rates_tables` are nested lookup fields.

The query is becoming slower as the database grows, so I tried to use an index

```
indexes = [models.Index(
    fields=['id', 'contracts__id', 'contracts__rates_tables']
)]
```

But I found that it is not possible to do so with columns from different tables.

This is the resulting query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."id",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."company_id", 
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."name", 
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."zone_id",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."category_id",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."capacity",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."position",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."in_pickup",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."is_active",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."latitude",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."longitude",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."iframe", 
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."logo",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."adults_only",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."minimum_age",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."handle_fee",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."user_id",
"ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."timestamp" 
FROM "ReservationsManagerApp_hotel" 
INNER JOIN "RatesManagerApp_contract" 
ON ("ReservationsManagerApp_hotel"."id" = "RatesManagerApp_contract"."hotel_id")
INNER JOIN "RatesManagerApp_ratestable" 
ON ("RatesManagerApp_contract"."id" = "RatesManagerApp_ratestable"."contract_id")
WHERE ("RatesManagerApp_ratestable"."due_date" >= 2018-09-14 AND
"RatesManagerApp_ratestable"."start_date" <= 2018-09-14)
```

What would be the best option to optimize this query?

Comment: could you provide the query output from this? str(hotels.query)

Comment: @brddawg I added it to the body of the question

Comment: my go to for this would be to start with the select from the ratestable where those fields match and join to the other two tables after in order to start with the smallest dataset and gather records that match in larger sets.